# How to find the index for all the elements in a list with a particular value in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists, one with the product's ID code and another with the price they were bought for.

I was planning on grouping them together in a list of lists with the first element being the product ID and the following elements being the prices as seen below:

```
product_id = [40, 56, 15, 17, 12, 39, 52, 41, 14, 19, 58, 42]
price_id = [1, 9, 25, 25, 25, 1, 9, 1, 25, 25, 9, 1]
list = [[1, 40, 39, 41, 42], [9, 56, 58, 52], [25, 12, 14, 19, 17, 15]]
```

I would prefer to do this without pandas but I was wondering how you could do this or if it would be better to just create a data frame with pandas and sort by product ID as this would make further coding easier and the remainder has been coded assuming this layout.

So far, I am planning on using a for loop to connect the index on the product list and price list together but I can't find all the indexes. I was thinking of something like this:

```
index_prod1 = [0, 5, 7, 11]
prod1 = [1]

for i in range(len(index_prod1)):
    prod1.append(price_id[i])

list = [prod1, prod9, prod25]
```

However, I was wondering how I could get `index_prod1`, would I have to do a for loop and just append each value?

That, and how could I make it more generalised so that if there were to be more products added to both lists the model would still work as this needs to work for changing amounts of products.

Comment: This seems like the job for a dict mapping from price_id to a list of product_id*s*, not a nested list where each first element has some special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

```py
product_id = [40, 56, 15, 17, 12, 39, 52, 41, 14, 19, 58, 42]
price_id = [1, 9, 25, 25, 25, 1, 9, 1, 25, 25, 9, 1]

out = {}
for a, b in zip(product_id, price_id):
    out.setdefault(b, []).append(a)

out = [[k, *v] for k, v in out.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 40, 39, 41, 42], [9, 56, 52, 58], [25, 15, 17, 12, 14, 19]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I went to upvote for you but apparently, I can't do that as a new user just yet, but this was great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question you could just use enumerate so you would do

```
for idx, i in enumerate(index_prod1):
```

I would be the value and idx would be the index
is that what you meant